# objective c - Using UIActivityViewController on iPhone X/XR/XS Max missing To field in Mail/iMessage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using a regular UIActivityViewController to share text with their services such as iMessage, Mail, Whatsapp, etc.  But on the iPhone X(> IOS 11), the "to field" is missing in Mail/iMessage so the user is unable to actually input a contact, phone number, or email address to send the content to.  Is there anything special I need to be doing for iPhone X?

Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

into

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

It will be fixed .

Comment: Could you please explain how your code solves OP's problem? That would really improve the answer.